# Nativescript + Angular: Transition ao fazer redirect

Tags: angular, nativescript

É possível criar um efeito de transição do tipo "slide" usando router outlet em uma aplicação construída com Angular + Native script?

Criando o efeito em um botão ou qualquer outro elemento tudo bem, meu problema é quando tento fazer isso dinamicamente.

Exemplo:

```js
var info = args.view.bindingContext;

let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: info
};

this.router.navigate(["/expense-details"], navigationExtras);
```

Gostaria de adicionar o efeito de transição "slide" ao direcionar para a página "/expense-details".

Comment: Você deu uma olhada nessa parte da documentação do angular? https://angular.io/guide/route-animations

Comment: Obrigado @VeroneseComS, olhei a documentação com mais cuidado e notei que ao usar o nativescript com Angular tem uma classe chamada "routerExtensions", bem parecida com a da documentação do Angular, e que é importada através do "nativescript-angular", usando ela eu consegui passar os parâmetros e fazer a animação que queria.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver importando o componente "RouterExtensions" do Nativescript.

```js
// Importa
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular";

// Redireciona passando parametros e animação
this.routerExtensions.navigate(['/expense-details'],
    {
        queryParams: info,
        animated: true,
        transition: {
            name: "slide",
            duration: 200,
            curve: "linear"
        }
    }
)
```

```css
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364816/nativescript-angular-transition-ao-fazer-redirect#
```